# How to use datepicker as daterangepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to use datepicker with predefined values and custom date select same as in daterangepicker

what i have try

```
 $('#id_date').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
   ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
      },
});
```

i have use **datepicker** plugin [this one](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: Does the documentation for whichever datepicker plugin you are using support that feature? Which plugin are you using and what is the behavior you are looking for? Please take some time to read [ask]

Comment: in documentation they haven't mention about it

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want the datepicker with some predefined dates and custom to add manual date

Comment: Really not clear what that means exactly

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ see the 1st eg of datepicker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145012/discussion-between-rahul-mohite-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery datepicker is only for single date piker not for daterange piker
try to use [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) plugin for this will work for both single date picker and daterangepicker.

Comment: i have tried daterangepicker but how to use it for single date piker and docs

Comment: just set this `$('#demo').daterangepicker({"singleDatePicker": true})`

Comment: you can see this [link](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#config) that will content all you need